# Carbon planet autotroph

Tags: aliens, flora, biochemistry

Life on a carbon planet is supposedly plausible. But what would the autotrophs, or plants, be like? The life would use hydrocarbons for a solevant, but that's all of the biochemistry I have fixed, although I've heard the chemicals wouldn't react as fast as ours so all physically reactions would be slowed. The atmosphere would be mostly carbon dioxide and monoxide with quite a bit of smog. Let's assume the sun is like Earth's for simplicity sake. The gravity of the planet too (I'm only human after all and not paying you guys anything). I also care more about the color and physical appearance than the biochemistry to be honest.

Comment: The autotrophs, or plants, would be like, amazing, like. They would be like mesmerizing visions of luxuriance, rising boldly in formless symmetrical knots, chiefly arranged in formal shrubberies as if the entire vital assemblage had been intricatelly designed by an English pupil of Le Nôtre pining for the fragrant Persian paradises where he had langurously lingered in sensuous abandon during his ill-spent Martial youth. They would be like the unboundedly exuberant daydreams of careless carousers revelling in the vitality of their slippery aliphatic youth, with just a *soupçon* of aromaticity.

Comment: @AlexP That's some scrumptious sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the planet has surface temperatures similar to Earth, in addition to having a sun similar to Earth's. Then the specific hydrocarbons used as a biosolvent are probably some mixture of pentanes, hexanes, and heptanes. Those are already pretty conveniently-sized chunks of reactive carbon to build biomolecules out of, so there will be very little need to "fix" oxidized carbon into organic forms. Instead, the major synthesis reactions will be dehydrogenation--removing hydrogens to form double bonds or to link smaller chains into larger ones. That would release small amounts of hydrogen into the atmosphere, except... your organisms will probably still need oxygen and nitrogen as heteroatoms in their organic biopolymers. So, autotrophs will consume CO and CO2, but not for the carbon, which they already have plenty of--rather, to fix the oxygen into organic forms. The hydrogen produced by dehydrogenation can be used to do that as an exothermic process, producing simple alcohols which can then be used as inputs into other biochemical processes to build oxygen-containing molecules. Excess hydrogen is also useful for fixing nitrogen.

So, your autotrophs would consume liquid hydrocarbons and atmospheric carbon oxides and nitrogen, and release, on average, nothing. Fermentation would regenerate small hydrocarbons and CO2, and probably some form of soluble, lipophilic nitrogen compounds (analogous to our uric acid & derivatives); if they used glucose for energy storage, they could produce methane and CO2, but they probably don't, as oxygen is not as plentiful on this world as it is on Earth, and their biochemistry would be adapted to a less-oxidizing environment--and given what their starting materials are, there isn't enough *hydrogen* in play to produce large amounts of methane. Thus, you would end up with neither oxygen breathers nor hydrogen breathers--this world would have no equivalent to respiration at all, just mildly endothermic synthesis, and mildly exothermic degradation.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but where do you get this from?

Comment: @JoeSmith general chemistry & biochemistry background knowledge. Most of the relevant processes occur in life on Earth. Just pick out the processes that can occur in the environment as specified, prune off the bits that couldn't, and make sure you don't end up with something that will "run to completion" and die out after completely transforming the planet.

Comment: To quote big bang theory, I know you think you're making sense but you're really not

Comment: @JoeSmith If there's something you don't understand, you'll have to be more specific about what it is if you want a better explanation.